# Select value if its row have some value excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

i have this list in sheet1

```
     A        B
1    name     id  
2    gggg     33
3    uuuu     12
4    ffff     1
```

and in other sheet2

```
    C        D
1   id       name
2   1        **I want the names to be  populated here automatic (ffff)
3   33       **I want the names to be  populated here automatic  (gggg)
4   12       **I want the names to be  populated here automatic   (uuuu)
5   13       will be echoed (No name) because it has no name
```

any  idea thanks ?

EDIT;

```
     =IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$251;SMALL(IF((Sheet1!$B$2:$B$251=C2);ROW(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$251)-ROW(Sheet1!$A$1));ROW(1:1)));"")
```

BUT this worked just for row 1 not for other rows .

Comment: which A:B ? you mean from sheet1 ?

Comment: @MátéJuhász Please look at edited table just to be fine looking and cleared what the name of every column and number . would you mind edit your comment so i can understand better thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an index match because you want to return something to the left of your lookup value

```
=Index(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$100,Match(C2,Sheet1!$B$2:$B$100,0))
```

Wrap it in an `iferror` to account for `(no name)`.

```
=IFERROR(indexmatch,"(no name)")
```

So Sheet2!D2 reads

```
=IFERROR(Index(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$100,Match(C2,Sheet1!$B$2:$B$100,0)),"(no name)")
```

Comment: i dont know but im getting no name . I have values

Comment: look i edited my try but its not working just for the first row .

Comment: You need to drag it down so that C2 turns to C3 etc

Comment: Why are you using `small` and `row` and `if`? Also my `,` will need to be turned to `;` for you

Comment: Yes i know i have dragged them all , and yes they turned c3 and c4 and so on . But it didnt work. my try was just try , im keeping to try to let your code working .

Comment: is it something that i click for it will be echoed as array ? something with {} ??

Comment: or something like this maybe ? ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA ??

Comment: I don't understand at all why you would need to return an array. It is an array formula. What's the issue?

Comment: no, i just want give you suggestion because it didnt work your solution thats why im trying to see whats wrong

Comment: my formula works if the data matches your description

Comment: IT WORKS !! you are right and you was suuuuure :) , thanks . it was some mistake

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get this working id by switching the order of the columns in your first file and using "VLOOKUP".

I have made a sample file for you that I uploaded to this website.

You can download the file and work with it.

[Please click here](http://downloadspalace.com/superuser/) Then click Superuser1120245.xls

If you have any questions, please feel free to ask.

Thank you

Comment: Similar comment as on your other answer where the answer is in a downloadable file.  Can you expand these two answers using those files?  Thanks.

Comment: thanks rhouba but i dont want switch order . i want get it with formel in any case . But @raystafarian have good answer which worked great for me .

Comment: Fixer1234 It looks like your have me under your microscope snooping around looking for all answers I made. 

Take a break dude, I already got your message the first time. Keep your energy for something or someone else.

Chill bro... What are you a Moderator an Admin or what exactly?

I don't know if you have noticed it or not, I'm not contributing no more... Relax.

Comment: @rhoula, I stumbled across your comment.  Just FYI, if you "address" a comment with @, like I did here, the person will get an alert to your post.  No microscope.  The site is moderated and curated by the community, and many experienced users make it a point to look at new posts on the main page and in review queues.  Your posts were among those.  It maintains the quality of the site and provides feedback to new users.  The site is a bit different from a forum and there can be a learning curve.  You obviously have knowledge to contribute, so I hope you do again.